# Find if the series converges $\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{\sqrt{n^3}+n^2+n^3+n^4}{4^{\frac{n}{2}}}\cdot x^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{\sqrt{n^3}+n^2+n^3+n^4}{4^{\frac{n}{2}}}\cdot x^n$$

Could somebody please describe the steps?

I managed to use quotientcriterium and receive: $\frac{1}{2}\cdot x \cdot \frac{\sqrt{(n+1)^3}+(n+1)^2+(n+1)^3+(n+1)^4}{\sqrt{n^3}+n^2+n^3+n^4}$, but i am not sure what to do next

Comment: From where you arrived, use Taylor series for $n\to \infty$ ans obtain $\frac x 2 \left(  1+\frac{4}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}
   \right)\right)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost done indeed

$$\frac{\sqrt{(n+1)^3}+(n+1)^2+(n+1)^3+(n+1)^4}{\sqrt{n^3}+n^2+n^3+n^4} \to1$$

and then

$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot |x| \cdot \frac{\sqrt{(n+1)^3}+(n+1)^2+(n+1)^3+(n+1)^4}{\sqrt{n^3}+n^2+n^3+n^4} \to \frac 12 |x| <1$$

which requires $-2<x<2$.

The cases $x=\pm 2$ are clearly divergent.

Comment: How did you solve it, so you got $...\to 1$?

Comment: Both numerator and denominator are $\sim n^4$.